# On a submanifold, every differential form can be extended to an open set containing the submanifold.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, tensors

I am going through Munkres' book *Analysis on Manifolds*. Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth $m$-dimensional submanifold. He defines a differential form of order $k$ on $M$ to be a smooth map $\omega$ where for each point $p\in M$, $\omega(p)$ is an alternating $k$-covector on the tangent space $T_pM$.

He states that "any differential form on $M$ can be extended to a differential form defined on an open set containing M, but the proof is decidedly nontrivial." That is if $\omega$ is a differential $k$-form on $M$ then there is a set $A$ which is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $M\subset A$ and a differential k-form $\bar{\omega}$ defined on all of $A$ such that $\forall p\in M$, $\omega(p)=\bar{\omega}(p)$.

How would I go about proving this? I have looked elsewhere for a proof, but I cannot find anything. Maybe we could do it locally and patch together with a partition of unity?

With this result, many of his cluttered statements of theorems would become cleaner. For example, he states Stokes' theorem as: If $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact oriented $k$-submanifold with boundary and $\omega$ is a $k-1$-form defined on an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$ containing $M$, then ... which seems messy. Using the above (unproven) result, Stokes' theorem becomes: If $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact oriented $k$-submanifold with boundary and $\omega$ is a $k-1$-form on $M$...

Comment: Do you know the tubular neighborhood theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just looked into the theorem and proof, but it uses the epsilon neighborhood theorem, which I don't know. The proof of this epsilon theorem uses the Whitney approximation theorem, which I also dont know, and so on. I guess this is what he meant by "decidedly nontrivial" ... Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Ok, then do you know about partition of unity?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you can extend locally and use a partition of unity to patch the extensions together.

Comment: So first, I need to do this when M is covered by a single coordinate patch.  Can you explain how I would go about doing this, in detail? Once this is done, I'm fairly confident I can use a partition of unity to prove it for arbitrary smooth manifolds.

Comment: Hint: Consider first the case of an m-dimensional linear subspace $M$ in $R^n$.